# Running multiple Backgrounds in one feature file on cucumber

Tags: cucumber

I haven't tried this but I'm theoretically assuming its bad practice to add multiple backgrounds in one feature file on Cucumber.

```
Background:
Given I am on the SignIn Page

Scenario: I am able to . .. . . .
When I . . . . .
Then I . . . . .

Background:
Given I signin
    
Scenario: I am able to . . . .
When I . . . .
Then I . . . .
```

Wanted to know if it is possible?

Thanks

Comment: Afaik you can only add one Background per feature file, so I'd expect you'd get a syntax error on your Gherkin file. This is something you could easily find out for yourself though.

Comment: Thanks Afaik, I just read it here https://cucumber.io/docs/gherkin/reference/#background

Answer (score 2):

Answer:

"You can only have one set of Background steps per Feature or Rule. If you need different Background steps for different scenarios, consider breaking up your set of scenarios into more Rules or more Features."

https://cucumber.io/docs/gherkin/reference/#background

... and since you can only have one Feature per file, it follows that you can only have one Background per file.